# "If someone would" - construction

Tags: conditionals, will-would-meaning-wanting-to

I have just read a passage from an adapted version of the Arabian Nights ([translated by Lang](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/128/128-h/128-h.htm)):

> "The rest is still more wonderful," replied Scheherazade, "and you
>   would say so, if the sultan would allow me to live another day, and
>   would give me leave to tell it to you the next night."

I struggle to understand the use of *if* + *would*. Would the following version of the same sentence be also **and/or** more than the one quoted above?

> "The rest is still more wonderful," replied Scheherazade, "and you would say so, if the sultan **allowed** me to live another day, and **gave** me leave to tell it to you the next night."

Comment: I believe that the two sentences have the same basic meaning, but the **would** in the first sentence does add an additional implied meaning.  I think that in this case, it is a sign of her submission to the will of the sultan, to imply his greater authority and power.  You lose that in the second sentence.

Comment: First, don't be surprised if English that's 200 years old doesn't work the same way you were taught in class. Second, using _if + would `V`_ is simply an older and somewhat more polite way of saying _if + `V-ed`_, i.e, the so-called "subjunctive".

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> First, don't be surprised if English that's 200 years old doesn't work the same way you were taught in class. Second, using *if + would `V`* is simply an older and somewhat more polite way of saying *if + `V-ed`*, i.e, the so-called "subjunctive".

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather think it's not a question of understanding the reason of the form, as in both versions we understand clearly the meaning, but of style. 
You could also may have found : "...would allow me.... & give me..." ; where the single "would" would be distributive to the 2 verbs *allow* & *give*.

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about the subjunctive mood combined with the future tense of *will*, and the mood is applied independently to each part of the condition `if X then Y`. The first *would* makes Y tentative: it's dependent on the `if X` clause but indicates a future point in time after `X`. The second *would* makes `X` also tentative. You may think this redundant, but in fact the sense of the sentence change if `X` were definite and not tentative.

The writer could have written:

> and you would say so, if the sultan allowed me to live another day.

This would be (sorry!) subtly different. This one indicates that the Sultan has *not* allowed the speaker to live another day, but considers what might have happened if that were not the case. This contrasts with the original example, in which the Sultan has not yet made his choice known, and so the situation being described is not exactly hypothetical: it might still come to pass that the Sultan will allow the speaker to live and therefore it might still come to pass that the addressee will "say so".

Note that if the construction had been *would* + *had* + *verb-pp*, you'd get a subjunctive mood about *the past*, similar to my first example above.

> and you would say so, if the sultan *would have allowed* me to live another day

Here, the second *would* indicates a different past. This strongly, but not necessarily, indicates that the Sultan has not allowed the speaker to live. However, the *would* merely suggests, not indicates. Thus, it's a hypothetical past, not a definite one.

Consider:

> If the train would have arrived 5 minutes ago, we would have caught it.

This does not necessarily indicate that the train *didn't* arrive 5 minutes ago. By contrast, this does:

> If the train had arrived 5 minutes ago, we would have caught it.